# What does this validation do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I know this validation checks for the presence of an e-mail before rendering an object as valid (in this case an user)

```
 validates :email, presence: true
```

But this one I have no idea what it does

```
 validates :login, :email, presence: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It validates both `:login` and `:email` using the `PresenceValidator`, same as writing:

```rb
 validates :login, presence: true
 validates :email, presence: true
```

Answer (score 0):

It add a presence validation to email and login.

[`validates`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) takes a list of attributes you want to validate and a hash containing the validations you want to apply. Which is handy if you want to apply the same validations to several attributes.

These are all equivalent:

```
validate_presence_of :email, presence: true
validate_presence_of :login, presence: true
# or
validates :email, presence: true
validates :login, presence: true
# or
validates :login, :email, presence: true
```

Comment: Thanks Max, more examples are more explanatoty.